# C# MVC4 Razor - can DisplayNameFor be used to get a Display(Name = ...) of a different model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

When I have a *Model* in my *View*, I can easily access a member's *DisplayName* by

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.myMember)
```

But when I need the *DisplayName* of a member from a different model there seems to be no easy solution, there are some that are digging in the *ModelMetaData* or *System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute*, but these are all some multistep things that are not easy to read or understand.

If you take a look at the definition of `DisplayNameFor`

```
DisplayNameFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModel>> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
)
```

It seems that it could be easily used by something like

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor<MyDifferentModel, string>(?, m => m.memberInMyDifferentModel)
```

but I don't get the clue about one of the parameters *TModel* is the model, *TValue* the type of my member, *Expression...* the `m => m.myMember` thingy, but what's that other parameter? Is it possible to use `DisplayNameFor` in that way? And what are the missing pieces?

Thanks for any suggestions - the examples in the www and on SO all handle just the case where you have the model in the view, nested models in the view, whatever what you can access directly by the model in the view, but that's not what I want.

**Edit:**

At the moment I use this helper function to get the display name

```
public string getDisplayName<Type>(string member)
{
    var type = typeof(Type);
    var memInfo = type.GetMember(member);
    var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute), false);
    var displayname = ((System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute)attributes[0]).Name;
        return displayname;
}
```

Can be easily used with

```
getDisplayName<MyDifferentModel>("memberInMyDifferentModel");
```

I just wondered if this functionality is already built in the HTML helper `DisplayNameFor` ...

Comment: `TModel` is the model in your view. What are you actually trying to do with this. Why are you not just including the properties you need in a view model?

Comment: I'm no fan of view models when it means that I copy tons of data from my model to the view model and back. I have my main model with main_model_id and some info and some external data in extra tables which look like (extra_id, main_model_id, some more info). In my View I simply call a helper function that gives me a string that joines all entries in that extra table, the caption for that string I'd like to take from the DisplayName of the member in that extra table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
[DisplayName("Sub-Category Name")]
public string subCategoryName { get; set; }

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.subCategoryName)
```

Comment: Isn't that the use I have for members in my model in the View? What's the difference of your answer to my first line of my question?

Answer (score 0):

After some research ... it seems that you have to create your own `Html`, so after

```
var MyHtml = new HtmlHelper<MyDifferentModel>(ViewContext, Html.ViewDataContainer)
```

in your view (don't know if it's a good idea or a problem to reuse the `ViewContext` and `ViewDataContainer` of the already instantiated `Html`), you can use

```
MyHtml.DisplayNameFor(m => m.memberInMyDifferentModel)
```

to get that display name. Or if you want it in one line ...

```
(new HtmlHelper<MyDifferentModel>(ViewContext, Html.ViewDataContainer)).DisplayNameFor(m => m.memberInMyDifferentModel)
```

While this seems to work (and seems to be a more clean solution than digging in annotations), there's something that I don't understand yet: why do you need to create a new `Html` and can't use the generics in `Html.DisplayNameFor<TModel,TValue>` directly? Please comment ...